# Pyspark: Comparing two different dataframes by looping through a reference list to create a flag

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables like below:

Table1: This shows the items that were bought by ppl in areas

```
PersonID    Item_Code   Item_Name   Area_code
5000        ABC-000     Item1       12345
5000        ABC-001     Item2       12345
5000        ABC-002     Item3       12345
5000        ABC-003     Item4       12345
5000        ABC-004     Item5       12345
5001        AAB-001     Item11      10000
5001        AAB-002     Item12      10000
5001        AAB-003     Item13      10000
5001        AAB-004     Item14      10000
5001        AAB-005     Item15      10000
```

Table 2: This has the list of all items that is available in that area.

```
Item_Code   Area_code
ABC-000     12345
ABC-001     12345
ABC-002     12345
ABC-003     12345
ABC-004     12345
AAB-001     10000
AAB-002     10000
AAB-003     10000
AAB-004     10000
AAB-005     10000
```

I'm trying to create a test to use table 2 as the master list (for count of items by area) and see if I'm getting the same (item code by area and count). So the end result should be whether the count of items by area match or not.

I can get the count by querying like this in Pyspark:

```
(df.filter((df.area_code == "12345")).groupBy('Item_count').count().count())
```

But I'm not sure how to create a function to compare these 2 tables using a large list of area codes. But the pseudo code is something like:

```
area_code_sample_list == [12345, 10000]

for i in area_code_sample_list:
  cnt1 = (df.filter((df.area_code == "i")).groupBy('Item_count').count().count())
  cnt2 = (df2.filter((df2.area_code == "i")).groupBy('Item_count').count().count())
  # compare cnt1 and cnt2 and create flag
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since it is spark, we can unleash the power of joins**. What you can do is :

1. Group by and count on `Item_code` and `Area_code` on Table 1 and get a dataframe (`df_1`)

   `df_1 = df_tb1.groupby(["Item_code", "Area_code"]).count()`
2. Similarly on Table 2 and get another dataframe (`df_2`)

   `df_2 = df_tb2.groupby(["Item_code", "Area_code"]).count()`
3. Do an **outer** join `df_1` and `df_2` on `Item_code` and `Area_code`

   `df_join = df_1.join(df_2, (df_1.Item_code == df_2.Item_code) & (df_1.Area_code == df_2.Area_code), how="outer").fillna(0)`
4. Compare the counts.